# clean stack in c++

Tags: c++

how can we clean the stack...

return statement is used to go out from the function. now

`if (m1.high_[0] < m2.low_[0]) return FALSE;`

here it have m1 and m2 two points with high[0],low[0], low[1] and high[1]  values..

now if we use return with statement than is this clean the stack.. i mean return statement with if condition is used to clean the stack.. is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, whenever a function returns by executing 'return XXXX', the stack frame for the concerned function is removed. Local automatic storage duration objects are destroyed in this process. Also it may involve manipulation of certain CPU registers (e.g. ESP, EBP on Intel) and is an implementation specific behavior. It does not matter if the return statement is executed in a condition or on the value which is being returned

EDIT 2:

In the code below, the local object 's' (which has automatic storage duration) is destroyed. The local object 'p' and 'x' are also destroyed, but the memory pointed to by 'p' which was newe'd is not deleted automatically until explicitly deleted is done (using delete). All this happens irrespective of when the function 'f' returns via 'return true' or 'return false'

```
struct S{};
bool f(int x){
   S s;
   S *p = new S;
   if(x == 2) return true;
   else return false;
}
```

Comment: OK but if i say if (m1.high_[0] < m2.low_[0]) return FALSE; return 0 or false that means stack clean but if i say return true is this mean that not clean the stack?

Comment: Remember that any memory you allocated with `new` will still be taken up, unless you explicitly `delete` it before the `return`.

Comment: No. false or true does not dictate the fact if the stack has to be cleaned up or not. returning from the function involves cleaning up the called function's stack frame irrespective of the value returned from the function.

Comment: so if i do't use the delete statement and direct go to return than that object will not destroy.. is it? and what bout if i say        if (m1.high_[0] < m2.low_[0]) return FALSE; return false means stack clean for m1 and m2 but if i say return true is this mean that not clean the stack

Comment: ok return is clear to me now if i use break with a function or if condition than what will happen?

Comment: OK return is used to free stack and go out from the Function.. than what break do if i use it with a if condition or in a function

Comment: break can not be used with if condition. it applies to for, do while, while, switch case statements.

Comment: why its apply, i mean it just break the statement and go out from the function its same as return..

Comment: actually i am seeing a switch statement and there it  break as my control check that case and from break it goes out from the function .. what it does mean? is this also cleaning the stack

Comment: Yes. It cleans up the objects that are declared in the scope of the catch condition from where it breaks out. This would also mean some stack adjustments practically. But since it did not exit the function, the function stack frame with it's appropriate local variables is still alive

Comment: do you mean that  the function on stack frame with it's appropriate local variables is still alive..but  break will clean up objects of catch scope not whole function will clean up from the stack.. whole function will still remain but object from the catch condition will break put.. right is it?

Comment: actually it declare a pM variable of string class type and assign value "F**F*****".. now when i run my code and see memory it show me Len =9 and _res =31 Len mean length that is total 9 but what is res??? is this defined in string class..

Comment: ohh i think i got it.. i thinks it s a hexa F= 16 so total result is 31.. what say?

Comment: i have more question can you give me time for it .. i mean by using any chat messenger..

Comment: sorry f you mind it.. anyhow my next question is about c_str().. actually what is c - string...

Comment: Please accept this answer if you are satisfied. Please raise a new question for the benefit of others also. Also you may get better responses when more people respond to your queries

Comment: a C string is a character sequence stored as a one-dimensional character array and terminated with a null character ('\0', called NUL in ASCII).  ok now my array is actully 2D and its using s_

Comment: and its using c_str().. why can i handle 2D array.

Answer (score 4):

You dont really "clean" the stack. All that happens is the stack pointer is reset to top of the calling programs stack storage.

Any subsequent function called from this program will be given the same stack pointer as your program receieved (including any values set by your program -- which is why its important to intialise automatic storage!)

Conversly when your program invokes a function the called function will be given a stack pointer of just after the last piece of your stack, and, if you call more than one function they will all end up with the same stack pointer.

---

To clarify C C++ programs support three types of storage allocation:-

"static" which is effectivly global to the compile unit. A suitable lump of storage is allocated when the main program starts and each "static" is allocated an address in this lump of starage. Which is used until the main program terminates.

"heap" this is a collection of storage areas managed by "malloc" with a little help from the underlying operating system. Most (but not all!) "new" objects allicate memory this way.

Then "automatic" storage (which is the default) uses the stack. Again this is fairly large contiguous area of storage allocated whne your main program starts. Any automatic variables used by "main" will be allocated to the begining of the stack and the stack pointer incremented to point to the word after the end of main's last variable.
When the first function is called it allocates its automatic variables starting from the current stack pointer and the stck pointer is set to the word after the end of its last variable, if if calls other functions then the process is repeated. When a function ends the stack pointer is reset to whatever value it had when the function was called.

In this way storage is constantly reused without the need for any mallocs or frees and it makes it easy to implement recursive functions as each call will get its own piece fo the stack (until the stack runs out!).

Comment: @ James: with your statement, its seems that stack keep all globe and local  variables and all that stuff.. but memory clean up actually happen in stack pointer.. we give pointer i mean let say int *a=&b now here its a pointer to int but if i do't give pointer than this variables will not removed. is it ? with your statement i jsut coem to know this.. actually what is stack.. stack is memory location now what si pointer that point to location of in stack so if i do't use pointer than my variable will not remove as control goes out from the function. is it?

Comment: This is correct with one caveat...  He also appears to be looking for where the return value is stored.  On X86-32 at least, it's stored in EAX if it fits (i.e. pointer, int32, int16, int8 etc), but...  Floating point values are returned on top of the floating point stack.  Off the top of my head I do not remember the X86-64 conventions, nor the conventions for X86-32 when something is too big to fit in EAX.

Comment: so actually all variables exits on memory.. right our memory clean up during execution of the program.. now by your all talking i come to knwo that actually our execution take place in stack pointer and with return statement this clean up but our variable still exits in the stack.. right now where is stack pointer

Comment: as i know stack pointer is pointing to a specific stack memory let say int *a=&; now if i dot use pointer than stack will not clean up after returning the function.. is it? because above say that clean up     memory take place in stack pointer..

Comment: +1 - great answer (: **@James Anderson** - just one thing - you said "Most (but not all!) "new" objects allicate memory this way" - what do you mean by "not all", in what situation, `operator new` will allocate the variable on some other place, that heap?